# True/False Proof

Tags: logic

I was trying to prove this problem but couldn't really figure out where to go.

The question is,

Let $O(x)$ be the assertion “$x$ is odd” and $E(x)$ be the assertion “$x$ is even”. Is the following
statement a true or false statement (justify your answer with a brief explanation):
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(E(x)) \implies  (\forall x \in \mathbb{Z})(O(x))$$

I'm really not sure where to go with this question.

Comment: This same question was just posted a few days ago. Let me look ...

Comment: The hypothesis of the implication is false, so the implication is true.

Comment: Thank you, I searched on the forum but I guess I wasn't able to catch it.

Comment: Well, darn, I can't find it either ... anyway, since not all integers are even, the antecedent (the 'if' part) of the conditional is false, and in logic we set the whole conditional to true, as soon as the antecedent is false, no matter the truth of the consequent (the 'then' part)

Comment: As a side note, if you somehow didn't notice the hypothesis was false, you could still prove the implication using the fact $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}, (E(x-1) \rightarrow O(x))$.

Comment: @Bram28 - correct; at least posted twice by difefrent users and then, it seems, deleted.

Comment: What does it mean "to prove it" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be easier if we look at the conditional one part at a time. First, what does the hypothesis mean?

$$(\forall x \in \Bbb{Z})(E(x))$$

This means that $E(x)$ holds for any $x \in \Bbb{Z}$. Thus, "$x$ is even" is true for any integer $x$. This is the same as saying all integers are even, which is clearly false.

Thus, since the hypothesis is false, the whole conditional is true, regardless of what the conclusion is. A conditional with a false hypothesis is always true. This shows that the whole conditional statement is indeed true.